# TFS 2010 Creating Work Items on behalf of others

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Just starting to implement things on TFS 2010. Been hunting around with no success so have resorted to posting the question.

When we get emails from users detailing a bug, or even suggesting a new feature, how can we create a TFS workitem on their behalf? We'd like to report on where/who the work items are coming from.

Having them create the item is not ideal as many of the users do not have TFS access, and may even be external clients.

Comment: Can you edit your template?  If so, you could add a field to specify a contact person; this may suit your needs as far as knowing where a work item is coming from.

Comment: So I'd create a whole new field for each work item type and adjust the workflow to use this new field? 

Seems kinda drastic when all I want to do is put their details in a pre-existing field that is already part of the existing workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The fields that are used for tracking use the credentials of the user that created the work item. If you want to track the customer who created the work item, you need to add a new field where you can store this information.

The CreatedBy field is available for you, but it is - hardcoded - readonly.

Do you know that it is also possible to let your external customers create their own bugs by using ["Work Item Only View"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx)? You don't need a CAL for your customer if you use this. In this mode, the customer can create new work items and see their own created work items.

Comment: Thanks Ewald. The WIOV won't really work. Surely there has been some thought about creating work items on behalf of others. What about PA's creating items for their boss, or a phone call about a new issue/bug? Sort of invalidates a lot of the reports and circumvents the workflow if everything is coming back to the creator of the item, not really the reporter of the item.

Comment: I hear you. For now you are bound to add a new field that contains that information. You can always add your suggestion to the User Voice site (http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).